# Open X11 Display of remote, in local and remote simultaneusly

Tags: ubuntu, x11, x11-forwarding

I have a local mahcine running Ubuntu and a remote machine running Ubuntu. Both are Ubuntu 12.04.I am trying to open up google-chrome of a remote machine in my local machine using the ssh command as given below.

```
ssh client@10.3.2.1 -Y
```

Then I could open google-chrome of that remote machine in my local machine by running `google-chrome` command. But if I already opened google chrome in that remote machine, then I wont be able to open it in my local machine, instead if I run the command `google-chrome` it will open up new google chrome windows in that remote machine. In fact, I need to open google chrome of a remote machine in my local machine and in that remote machine simultaneously. Is there any way or any options to be given with ssh ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It isn't X related, but rather chrome itself. Try `google-chrome --new-window`

Comment: This created a new chrome window in remote machine.

Comment: COnsider this scanario: Chrome is running in remote machine. I just want to ssh to that remote machine and run remote chrome to open up in my local machine.

Comment: Not sure i got it right. You launching it on remote via ssh, and it displays on your X only if there is no already running session on remote?

Comment: yes. you got that right.

Comment: Well, you have to disable chrome's session management someway. No ideas how, tho. Try asking in chrome mailing lists.